Role of Lebesgue number in the standard proof of homotopy lifting

Let $F:I\times I\to X$ be a continuous map such that $F(0,t)=F(1,t)=x_0$ for $t\in [0,1]$.Then there is a unique continuous map $\tilde F:I\times I\to \tilde X$ such that $p\circ \tilde F=F$ and $\tilde F(0,t)=\tilde x_0,t\in [0,1]$.
Copied from here

I am trying now to understand the proof of this which involves the Lebesgue number.
This is what I understand so far:
If we were to have the additional assumption that $F(I^2)$ is open in $X$ over which the projection is a trivial covering, then statement is quite easy to prove.
Due to this fact, the idea is to sub divide the domain such that in the individual fragments $F$ is an open map. So far so clear. Now start's the problem.
We consider by taking open Neighborhoods about every point $X$, and pull it back through $f$. Now, we have to consider for some reason the Lebesgue number and think of splitting the domain into cubes.
I am trying to understand why this is the choice of split, and why we need the Lebesgue number here. Could someone explain?
Remark: The crucial point of the proof seems to be that $ \left[0,1 \right]$ is a compact metric space.

Isn't the point that the Lebesgue number guarantees your pieces fall into the correct sheet up in the cover, making everything consistent?

Could you elaborate, perhaps with a picture? @Randall

I don't think the additional assumption that $F(I^2)$ be open in $X$ is of any possible use at all, so your understanding so far is flawed. For instance, in the case that $X$ is a compact connected manifold, there always exists a continuous surjective function $F : I \times I \to X$, hence $F(I^2)=X$ is open; but this is a very hard case to handle, I do not believe there are any shortcuts which make the statement "quite easy to prove" in this case.

How so? The projection of covering is defined so pre image of an open is homdomorphic to any covering sheet @Lee Mosher

You should go and read the actual definition of a covering map. The condition you write is not guaranteed to hold for any open subset of the base space of the covering map.

I believe I corrected it @LeeMosher

I suggest you read the proof in a good topology book. Munkres explains very clearly how the Lebesgue number lemma is used first in lifting paths (where the construction is more straighttforward) and then in lifting homotopies (where the construction is more complicated due to one higher dimension).

You have a cover $p: E \to X$.  (Assume whatever kind of connectivity assumptions you need in order to make what I say true.)  You wish to know that a homotopy $F: I \times I \to X$ lifts uniquely once you've chosen a point in the fiber to start the process.
The only way to do this is to build the lift in patches.  You first define the lift $\tilde{F}$ on the left-vertical and bottom-horizontal legs, which you can do by path-lifting.  You will lift it on the rest of the square by doing consistent things to little sub-rectangles. How, though?  This is where Lebesgue covering matters.
Start by covering $X$ by evenly-covered open sets, say $U_\alpha$ ($\alpha$ ranging over some index set). Then $I \times I$ gets covered by the open sets $F^{-1}(U_\alpha)$. By Lebesgue covering applied to this cover (and the compactness of $I \times I$) you are gauranteed a subdivision of $I$ into little rectangles $I_{ij}$ exists so that all $I_{ij}$ all have the property that $F(I_{ij})$ land within some $U_\alpha$, an evenly-covered neighborhood in $X$.  Now the proof goes on....

How do you know they match up on the intersections?

Because you define them that way.

Read a good proof, and you will see how they are defined so as to match up on the intersections.
